# Ajax doesnt hit controller action

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

lam trying to save replycomments to the database 
here is my  html form,

```
<div id="replyform" class="card my-4 d-none">
    <h5 class="card-header">Cevap Yaz:</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="replytext" name="replytext" typeof="text" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="sendreply" name="sendreply" class="btn btn-primary">Cevap Yaz</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my homecontroller action code

```
 public JsonResult ReplyComment(string replycomment, int articleid,int commentid)
    {
        var UserId = Session["UserId"];
        if (replycomment == null)
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        db.ReplyComments.Add(new ReplyComment
        { UserId = Convert.ToInt32(UserId), ArticleId = articleid, CommentId=commentid, Paragraph = replycomment,  Date = DateTime.Now });
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and my ajax code is here

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#sendreply").click(function () {

        var r_comment = $("#replytext").val();
        var r_commentid = $(".astar").val();

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("ReplyComment","Home")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { replycomment: r_comment, articleid:@Model.ArticleId, commentid: r_commentid },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            alert("İşlemOkey");
            }
        });
});
})
```

l cant call the Replycomment action with this code

Comment: You need a way to prevent the default behaviour of your `submit` button..you can do it using `preventDefault` for example... you can replace this line `$("#sendreply").click(function () {` with this one `$("#sendreply").click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); `

Comment: I am new on this  please can you write the full ajax code please

Comment: Is just a replace.....replace your current line with the new one and try again!

Comment: İt didnt work  problem is same

Comment: I am using different forms normal comment and replycomment 
When user click answer button opens a new form if you thought l am using same form for two action

Comment: What is happening with your current code ? BTW, you need `e.preventDefault();` or `return false` to prevent the normal form submit behavior

Comment: Commen part is working fine but there is a problem with reply system

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code and it will work for you. since am posting via ajax, i have removed the form tags from the body of the html.

For backend(php), I just test it by sending variables r_comment and r_commentid and it works fine. it should work with your backend code now. Give me a shout if it works for you...........

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

         $(document).ready(function(){

          $("#sendreply").click(function () {



       var r_comment = $("#replytext").val();
       var r_commentid = $(".astar").val();
       var articleid = '20';
/* lets test with data

        var r_comment ='my comment';
        var r_commentid = '20';

        */
        $('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('Data is being processed');


         // assuming that you want query result by posting a variable
         var datasend = "r_comment="+ r_comment  + "&r_commentid=" + r_commentid  + "&articleid=" + articleid;

         $.ajax({

         type:'POST',
         url:'smoke1.php',
         data:datasend,
         crossDomain: true,
         cache:false,
         success:function(msg){

//display image loader or text to alert the use that content is being processed

         $('#loader').hide();

// and display result
alert("İşlemOkey");

         $('#result').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);




         }

         });

      })

         });


    </script>


<div id="replyform" class="card my-4 d-none">
    <h5 class="card-header">Cevap Yaz:</h5>
    <div class="card-body">



            <div class="form-group">
               replytext: <textarea id="replytext" name="replytext" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>

<div class="form-group">
                astar: <input type="text" class="astar">
            </div>



<div id="loader"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
<br>


            <button type="submit" id="sendreply" name="sendreply" class="btn btn-primary">Cevap Yaz</button>

    </div>
</div>


</body></html>
```

my testing backend in php(Try it with yoour backend code)

**smoke1.php**

```
<?php
echo "ok";
echo $_POST['r_comment'];
echo $_POST['r_commentid'];
echo $_POST['articleid'];
?>
```

Comment: l dont know php but it looks same on my page. nothing different

Comment: php part does not concern you. it just for you to see that the ajax can submit data when the button its hit as per title of your question. change ajax url to the actual url of your backend. it will work. I removed the form tags<form></form> so that the ajax will work

Comment: my code will work for you. its not the same with yours. have you tested it or your just complaining

Comment: I fixed this problem but now when l try to reply a comment 
Commentid is taking first comment id  everytime if l want to reply another comment doesnt change the comment id do you know how can l fix that mate ?

Comment: Now you problem is solved as per the title of your question (Ajax doesnt hit controller action). You can mark the question as solved. You can open another post and create a title why commentid is taking the first comment id. okay